# Select rows if string begins with certain characters in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a csv file as the given picture bellow

[image]

I'm trying to find any word that will start with letter A and G or any list that I want

but my code returns an error any Ideas what I'm doing wrong ? 
this is my code

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print("please provide a CSV file to analys")
else:
    fileinput = sys.argv[1]

wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput)


print( list(filter(startswith("a","g"), wdata)) )
```

Comment: What error you received ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with convert list to tuple and filtering by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
wdata = pd.DataFrame({'words':['what','and','how','good','yes']})

L = ['a','g']
s = wdata.loc[wdata['words'].str.startswith(tuple(L)), 'words']
print (s)
1     and
3    good
Name: words, dtype: object
```

Comment: but this returns anything with a and g not just the start my condition is if it starts with this letter then return

Comment: @programmingfreak - Added sample data, for me working nice.

Answer (score 11):

To get relevant rows, extract the first letter, then use `isin`:

```
df
  words  frequency
0  what         10
1   and          8
2   how          8
3  good          5
4   yes          7

df[df['words'].str[0].isin(['a', 'g'])]
  words  frequency
1   and          8
3  good          5
```

If you want a specific column, use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['words'].str[0].isin(['a', 'g']), 'words']
1     and
3    good
Name: words, dtype: object

df.loc[df['words'].str[0].isin(['a', 'g']), 'words'].tolist()
# ['and', 'good']
```

Comment: first method just returns those which start with a not for some reasons

Comment: @programmingfreak I don't understand what you mean, this gives the exact same result as the accepted answer

Comment: my sample set is much bigger and for some reason it was just returning the first condition but the second method is interested and works fine for me thanks man

Answer (score 1):

it is very easy and handy. you can just use `str.startwith` in this way:

```
df[df.Words.str.startswith('G')]



df[df.Words.str.startswith('A')]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).