# Python.pandas: how to select rows where objects start with letters 'PL'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have specific problem with pandas: I need to select rows in dataframe which start with specific letters. 
Details: I've imported my data to dataframe and selected columns that I need. I've also narrowed it down to row index I need. Now I also need to select rows in other column where objects START with letters 'pl'.

[image: Pasted here picture of how df looks like now for better view]

Is there any solution to select row only based on first two characters in it?

I was thinking about

```
pl = df[‘Code’] == pl*
```

but it won't work due to row indexing. Advise appreciated!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Select rows if string begins with certain characters in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926723/select-rows-if-string-begins-with-certain-characters-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a string method on the Series that should return you a true/false result. You can then use that as a filter combined with .loc to create your data subset.

```
new_df = df.loc[df[‘Code’].str.startswith('pl')].copy()
```

Answer (score 21):

Use `startswith` for this:

```
df = df[df['Code'].str.startswith('pl')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Fully reproducible example for those who want to try it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["plusieurs", 1], ["toi", 2], ["plutot", 3]])

df.columns = ["Code", "number"]

df = df[df.Code.str.startswith("pl")] # alternative is df = df[df["Code"].str.startswith("pl")]
```

Answer (score 3):

The condition is just a filter, then you need to apply it to the dataframe. as filter you may use the method [`Series.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html?highlight=startswith#pandas.Series.str.startswith) and do

```
df_pl = df[df['Code'].str.startswith('pl')]
```

Comment: This is the same as the other answer.